# Can @BeforeMethod present in one Test Class be applicable to a method in another Test Class?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, annotations, testng

I have two different test classes:

```
public class Class A{

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeEachMethod(){
//}

@Test(groups = "Login")
public void testA(){
//}
}

@public class Class B{

@Test(dependsOnGroups = "Login")
public void methodB(){
//}

}
```

But right now the @BeforeMethod is invoked only for the method in Class A. It is not getting invoked for the method in Class B even though the method in Class B runs successfully.

I want the @BeforeMethod in public Class A to be invoked for the method in Class B too.

I want the @BeforeMethod to be present in only the Class A and I would have several other classes like Class B, Class C, Class D etc. Is it possible to get that one single @BeforeMethod invoked for all the other classes?

Answer (score 2):

The method `beforeEachMethod()` belongs to class `A`, so it will run only when tests in class `A` are executed. If you want it to run before each test you can create an abstract base class with that method and have every test class to inherit from it

```
public class TestCase {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeEachMethod() {
    }
}

public class A extends TestCase {

    @Test(groups = "Login")
    public void testA() {
    }
}

public class B extends TestCase {

    @Test(dependsOnGroups = "Login")
    public void methodB() {
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't satisfy this condition : I want the @BeforeMethod to be present in only the Class A

Comment: @cruisepandey Then you will have to call it explicitly. Those are the options you have.

Comment: Thanks. I actually already have another class which I am extending to every test class. It has ExtentReport methods and Screenshot methods apart from wait methods used by every test class. It's not an abstract class. How does using an Abstract class instead of a normal parent class which I'm extending,  help here? Do I have to make it abstract?

Comment: @SteroidKing666 It doesn't matter to your question if the base class is abstract or not, making it abstract or not has other reasons.

Comment: In my case, I will always have to extend my normal class. How can I utilize the Abstract Class in this situation?

Comment: @SteroidKing666 Put the method in your base class. I also edited my answer and deleted the abstract.